# Navigation not pulling less variables

Tags: html, css, json, less

I have a navigation just the way I want, however it's not pulling the less variables for the colors that I've created in // tweak

The @nav-color-active works just fine, however @navc-color and @nav-color-hover does not. Why is this?

The site I am working on is https://centrecorp.squarespace.com/

```
    // tweak: { type: 'color', title: 'Navigation Links', target: '.main-navigation'}
@nav-color: #000000;

// tweak: { type: 'color', title: 'Navigation Links (Hover)', target: '.main-navigation'}
@nav-color-hover: #8963f2;

// tweak: { type: 'color', title: 'Navigation Links (Active)', target: '.main-navigation'}
@nav-color-active: #8963f2;

    .main-navigation {
    .nav-font;
    float:right;
  ul {  
    padding-left: 0;

    li  {
      display: inline-block;
      color:@nav-color;

      ul {
        display: none;
      }

      &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: .5em;
      }

      &:hover > ul {
        display: inline-block;
        color:@nav-color-hover;
      }

      &.active-link > a {
         color:@nav-color-active;
      }

      &.active-folder > a {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the colors on    `.main-navigation li a{`     and  `.main-navigation li a:hover`

you have them on `li` which would work but the href will over-ride those styles.

** ===================///// EDIT /////=================== **

```
.main-navigation {
    .nav-font;
    float:right;
  ul {  
    padding-left: 0;

   li  {
      display: inline-block;
      a{
        color:@nav-color;
        &:hover{color:@nav-color-hover;}
      }

   ul {
        display: none;
      }

      &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: .5em;
      }

      &:hover > ul {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      &.active-link > a {
         color:@nav-color-active;
      }

      &.active-folder > a {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I'd need to change 'main-navigation { li {' in 'main-navigation { li a {' and create 'main-navigation { li a:hover {' after that?

Comment: I appended the above with what i think the less should be. My LESS Compiler is down so i did not tested but i think you will get it from above... Let me know if this helps!

Comment: You rock! It work's beautifully! Thanks so much.

Would you mind explaining why I had to put it in li {} ?

Comment: 2 forms of logic to explain... You nest them in LESS the same way and order your HTML is nested... Or you can also understand by looking at how you would write in css.